# My theme header is stuck on a low resolution image?

Tags: post-thumbnails, responsive, custom-header

My responsive header is stuck on the medium-large srcset regardless of width UNLESS I'm in DevTools. I have disabled all CDN's and image resizing, but now this seems to be browser behavior i cannot control.

Please take a look, then look at the image in DevTool. When set to the same width as the browser the image is clear, when I maintain width but turn off DevTools, the header image is now blurry. Can you help me?

https://mccustage.wpengine.com/blog/

Comment: This seems like it has something to do with Jetpack Photon which you may be able to disable in the plugin settings.

Comment: It was the src-set/sizes selecting a smaller image as the window gets huge, to account for content max-width. But as a 100% hero img, this is not the best choice. I used jQuery to set the sizes atr to '100vw' for all header images, and it worked out!